# Regex to match a domain with only one subdomain

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i'm trying to create a regex for my .htaccess that matches Domains that have only one subdomain

Example

- test1.subdomain.ourdomain.de **no match**
- subdomain.ourdomain.de **match** => redirect to default.subdomain.ourdomain.de

What I've got till now is this ugly thing:

```
^([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.ourdomain\.de$
```

It matches test1.subdomain.ourdomain.de but not without test1. How to negate this correctly? My attempts with negative lookaheads did not work :-(

Try here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example htaccess will redirect from `subdomain.ourdomain.de` to `default.subdomain.ourdomain.de`, and there will be no match on `http://first1.subdomain.ourdomain.de`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.ourdomain.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://default.subdomain.ourdomain.de/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

To match **any 1-subdomain URL**, you need to use correct capture group with a corresponding `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://default.%1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

*Input*:
`http://tes1.clothes.germany.de`

*Output*: `<NOTHING>` as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]` condition was not met

*Input 2*:
`http://clothes.germany.de`

*Output URL*:
`http://default.clothes.germany.de/`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
```

Here `^[^\.]+` will match the pattern upto a `.` at the beginning of the line, then we have matched a literal `.`, then match upto a `.`, then again `.`  and then at the last we match any pattern that does not have `.` at the end of the line.